# Global keybinding on X using Python gtk3

Tags: python, linux, xlib, gtk3

I was looking for some example of python xlib global keybinding that would work with gtk3, just as it is done for gtk2 at http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/239. Very similar code here:

```
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib import X
import gtk.gdk
import threading
import gobject

class GlobalKeyBinding (gobject.GObject, threading.Thread):
    __gsignals__ = {
            'activate': (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, gobject.TYPE_NONE, ()),
        }


    def __init__ (self):
        gobject.GObject.__init__ (self)
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)
        self.setDaemon (True)

        self.keymap = gtk.gdk.keymap_get_default ()
        self.display = Display ()
        self.screen = self.display.screen ()
        self.root = self.screen.root

        self.map_modifiers ()
        self.keybindings={}
        self.current_signal=None

    def map_modifiers (self):
        gdk_modifiers = (gtk.gdk.CONTROL_MASK, gtk.gdk.SHIFT_MASK, gtk.gdk.MOD1_MASK,
                         gtk.gdk.MOD3_MASK, gtk.gdk.MOD4_MASK, gtk.gdk.MOD5_MASK,
                         gtk.gdk.SUPER_MASK, gtk.gdk.HYPER_MASK)
        self.known_modifiers_mask = 0
        for modifier in gdk_modifiers:
            self.known_modifiers_mask |= modifier

    def add_grab_key(self,accelerator,signal):
        if not accelerator:
            return
        keyval,modifiers=gtk.accelerator_parse(accelerator)
        if not keyval or not modifiers:
            return
        keycode=self.keymap.get_entries_for_keyval(keyval)[0][0]
        self.keybindings[signal]=[accelerator,
            keycode,
            int (modifiers)]
                #grab_key operation forces X to exclusivelly send given keycode (like apostrophe char) to current X client (unless other X client grabbed it before).
                #`X.AnyModifier' parameter tells to register the keycode for all modifiers, thus Ctrl-', Alt-', Shift-', ' will all be sent to this X client.
                # given keyval is grabbed by current X client until `ungrab_key' is called.
        return self.root.grab_key (keycode, X.AnyModifier, True, X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeSync)



    def ungrab (self):
        for signal in self.keybindings:
                    # ungrab_key ungrabs given keycode, that was grabbed by `grab_key'.
            self.root.ungrab_key (self.keybindings[signal][1],X.AnyModifier, self.root)
        self.keybindings={}

    def idle (self):
        if self.current_signal:
            gtk.gdk.threads_enter ()
            self.emit (self.current_signal)
            self.current_signal=None
            gtk.gdk.threads_leave ()
        return False

        #threading.Thread.start() method invokes this method.
    def run (self):
        self.running = True
        wait_for_release = False
        while self.running:
            event = self.display.next_event () # registered keycode(or probably rather event) has been received.
            if self.current_signal:
                self.display.allow_events (X.ReplayKeyboard, event.time)
                continue

            try:
                if not wait_for_release and event.type == X.KeyPress:
                    modifiers = event.state & self.known_modifiers_mask
                                        print modifiers, event.detail
                    for signal in self.keybindings:
                        if self.keybindings[signal][1] == event.detail and self.keybindings[signal][2] == modifiers:
                            self.this_signal=signal
                            this_keycode = self.keybindings[signal][1]
                            wait_for_release=True
                            break
                    if wait_for_release:
                        self.display.allow_events (X.AsyncKeyboard, event.time)
                    else:
                        self.display.allow_events (X.ReplayKeyboard, event.time)
                    continue
                elif wait_for_release and event.detail == this_keycode and event.type == X.KeyRelease:
                    wait_for_release = False
                    self.current_signal=self.this_signal
                    self.event_window=event.window
                    gobject.idle_add (self.idle)
                    self.display.allow_events (X.AsyncKeyboard, event.time)
                else:
                    self.display.allow_events (X.ReplayKeyboard, event.time)
            except:
                self.display.allow_events (X.ReplayKeyboard, event.time)
    def stop (self):
        print "stopping keybindings thread..."
        self.running = False
        self.ungrab ()
        self.display.close ()

# SAMPLE USAGE
def callback (keybinding):
    print 'Callback!'
    keybinding.stop()
    gtk.main_quit ()

def main():
    print "starting..."
    gtk.gdk.threads_init ()
    keybindings=GlobalKeyBinding()
    keybindings.add_grab_key('<Control>apostrophe','activate')
    keybindings.connect('activate',callback)
    keybindings.start () # let's thart the thread
    gtk.main ()

main()
```

Unfortunately I didn't find one, thus I decided to reimplement it to use gtk3 (ubuntu 12.04). Below is the result. It does not have runtime errors, but unfortunatelly it does not grab any input.

```
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib import X
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject
import threading

class GlobalKeyBinding (GObject.GObject, threading.Thread):
    __gsignals__ = {
            'activate': (GObject.SignalFlags.RUN_LAST, None, ()),
        }


    def __init__ (self):
        GObject.GObject.__init__ (self)
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)
        self.setDaemon (True)

        self.keymap = Gdk.Keymap.get_default()
        self.display = Display ()
        self.screen = self.display.screen ()
        self.root = self.screen.root

        self.map_modifiers ()
        self.keybindings={}
        self.current_signal=None

    def map_modifiers (self):
        gdk_modifiers = (Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK, Gdk.ModifierType.SHIFT_MASK, Gdk.ModifierType.MOD1_MASK,
                         Gdk.ModifierType.MOD3_MASK, Gdk.ModifierType.MOD4_MASK, Gdk.ModifierType.MOD5_MASK,
                         Gdk.ModifierType.SUPER_MASK, Gdk.ModifierType.HYPER_MASK)
        self.known_modifiers_mask = 0
        for modifier in gdk_modifiers:
            #print modifier,modifier+0
            self.known_modifiers_mask |= modifier

    def add_grab_key(self,accelerator,signal):
        if not accelerator:
            return
        keyval,modifiers=Gtk.accelerator_parse(accelerator)
        if not keyval or not modifiers:
            return
        #keycode=self.keymap.get_entries_for_keyval(keyval)[0][0]
                success, entries = self.keymap.get_entries_for_keyval(keyval)
                entry = [(int(i.keycode), i.group, i.level) for i in entries]
                if not entry:
                    raise TypeError("Invalid key name")

                keycode=entry[0][0]
        self.keybindings[signal]=[accelerator,
            keycode,
            int (modifiers)]
        return self.root.grab_key (keycode, X.AnyModifier, True, X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeSync)



    def ungrab (self):
        for signal in self.keybindings:
            self.root.ungrab_key (self.keybindings[signal][1],X.AnyModifier, self.root)
        self.keybindings={}

    def idle (self):
        if self.current_signal:
            Gdk.threads_enter ()
            self.emit (self.current_signal)
            self.current_signal=None
            Gdk.threads_leave ()
        return False

    def run (self):
        self.running = True
        wait_for_release = False
        while self.running:
            event = self.display.next_event ()
            if self.current_signal:
                self.display.allow_events (X.ReplayKeyboard, event.time)
                continue

            try:
                if not wait_for_release and event.type == X.KeyPress:
                    modifiers = event.get_state() & self.known_modifiers_mask
                    print modifiers,event.get_state()
                    for signal in self.keybindings:
                        if self.keybindings[signal][1] == event.detail and self.keybindings[signal][2] == modifiers:
                            self.this_signal=signal
                            this_keycode = self.keybindings[signal][1]
                            wait_for_release=True
                            break
                    if wait_for_release:
                        self.display.allow_events (X.AsyncKeyboard, event.time)
                    else:
                        self.display.allow_events (X.ReplayKeyboard, event.time)
                    continue
                elif wait_for_release and event.detail == this_keycode and event.type == X.KeyRelease:
                    wait_for_release = False
                    self.current_signal=self.this_signal
                    self.event_window=event.window
                    GObject.idle_add (self.idle)
                    self.display.allow_events (X.AsyncKeyboard, event.time)
                else:
                    self.display.allow_events (X.ReplayKeyboard, event.time)
            except:
                self.display.allow_events (X.ReplayKeyboard, event.time)
    def stop (self):
        self.running = False
        self.ungrab ()
        self.display.close ()

# SAMPLE USAGE
def callback (keybinding):
    print 'Callback!'
    keybinding.stop()
    Gtk.main_quit ()

def main():
    print "starting..."
    Gdk.threads_init ()
    keybindings=GlobalKeyBinding()
    keybindings.add_grab_key('<Control>apostrophe','activate')
    keybindings.connect('activate',callback)
    print "keybindings go"
    keybindings.start () # let's thart the thread
    print "gtk go"
    Gtk.main ()

main()
```

Maybe You have some ideas how to make it work?

best regards,
Paul

Answer (score 3):

Hey i implemented same code and working great, you can try this. but there is no warranty. If you find missing parts please tell me.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8; -*-
# Copyright (C) 2013  Özcan Esen <ozcanesen@gmail.com>
# Copyright (C) 2008  Luca Bruno <lethalman88@gmail.com>
#
# This a slightly modified version of the globalkeybinding.py file which is part of FreeSpeak.
#   
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell   
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#   
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#   
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,  
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
# FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER    
# DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib import X, error
#import GObject
#import gtk.gdk
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject, GLib
import threading
from config import ConfigManager

class GlobalKeyBinding(GObject.GObject, threading.Thread):
    __gsignals__ = {
        'activate':(GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, None,()),
        }

    def __init__(self):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setDaemon(True)

        self.keymap = Gdk.Keymap.get_default()
        self.display = Display()
        self.screen = self.display.screen()
        self.root = self.screen.root
        self.ignored_masks = self.get_mask_combinations(X.LockMask | X.Mod2Mask | X.Mod5Mask)
        self.map_modifiers()

    def map_modifiers(self):
        gdk_modifiers =(Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK, Gdk.ModifierType.SHIFT_MASK, Gdk.ModifierType.MOD1_MASK,
                         Gdk.ModifierType.MOD2_MASK, Gdk.ModifierType.MOD3_MASK, Gdk.ModifierType.MOD4_MASK, Gdk.ModifierType.MOD5_MASK,
                         Gdk.ModifierType.SUPER_MASK, Gdk.ModifierType.HYPER_MASK)
        self.known_modifiers_mask = 0
        for modifier in gdk_modifiers:
            if "Mod" not in Gtk.accelerator_name(0, modifier):
                self.known_modifiers_mask |= modifier

    def grab(self):
        Gdk.threads_enter()
        accelerator = ConfigManager.get_conf('global-key')
        Gdk.threads_leave()
        keyval, modifiers = Gtk.accelerator_parse(accelerator)
        if not accelerator or(not keyval and not modifiers):
            self.keycode = None
            self.modifiers = None
            return

        self.keycode= self.keymap.get_entries_for_keyval(keyval)[1][0].keycode
        self.modifiers = int(modifiers)

        catch = error.CatchError(error.BadAccess)
        for ignored_mask in self.ignored_masks:
            mod = modifiers | ignored_mask
            result = self.root.grab_key(self.keycode, mod, True, X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeSync, onerror=catch)
        self.display.sync()
        if catch.get_error():
            return False
        return True

    def ungrab(self):
        if self.keycode:
            self.root.ungrab_key(self.keycode, X.AnyModifier, self.root)

    def get_mask_combinations(self, mask):
        return [x for x in xrange(mask+1) if not (x & ~mask)]

    def idle(self):
        Gdk.threads_enter()
        self.emit("activate")
        Gdk.threads_leave()
        return False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        wait_for_release = False
        while self.running:
            event = self.display.next_event()
            self.current_event_time = event.time
            if event.detail == self.keycode and event.type == X.KeyPress and not wait_for_release:
                modifiers = event.state & self.known_modifiers_mask
                if modifiers == self.modifiers:
                    wait_for_release = True
                    self.display.allow_events(X.AsyncKeyboard, event.time)
                else:
                    self.display.allow_events(X.ReplayKeyboard, event.time)
            elif event.detail == self.keycode and wait_for_release:
                if event.type == X.KeyRelease:
                    wait_for_release = False
                    GLib.idle_add(self.idle)
                self.display.allow_events(X.AsyncKeyboard, event.time)
            else:
                self.display.allow_events(X.ReplayKeyboard, event.time)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.ungrab()
        self.display.close()
```